# How to log into a Web API service

Tags: c#, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorize-attribute

I have a C# WebAPI application and would like to know the best way to log a user in such that a call can be made to a function that has the `Authorize` attribute.

Here is the code I wish to call once logged in:

```
[Authorize]
public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }

    return product;
}
```

How should this be done?

I see that there is a `WebSecurity.Login` function, but how should I call this function? Do I need to worry about doing this securely?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question around what to do on the client? For the server you can just start with a template with authentication turned on.

Comment: Yes, on the client. How can a client log in so that the user is then authenticated to call the GetProduct function.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this sample, it's rather large but it takes you through authorizing in multiple types of clients:

[ https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/Todo/ReadMe.txt ][1]